# Saber que um button foi clicado

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber que um certo Button foi clicado, para que não passe na validação de nulo.
Segue código:

```
//OnClick da tela de registro
btnRegistrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_registrar_button);
btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegistrarActivity.class);
        //startNewIntent("registrar");
    }
});
```

Mas antes de abrir a activity ele passa nesta validação:

```
if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && (!btnRegistrar.isPressed()))) {
    mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
    mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
    focusView = mEmailView;
    cancel = true;
```

Este "isPressed()" foi uma das tentivas.
Obrigado!

Edit: Ao clicar no botão ele chama esta validação, utilizei o template de login do android studio

Edti2: Reesolvido a questão, era erro de codificação. Não consigo apagar a pergunta.

Comment: Você só efetuará o registro se o botão não estiver pressionado ?

Comment: Já pensou em usar uma variavel global como flag? ou não curte muito fazer gamibarra hehe

Comment: Opa, talvez tenha ficado incompleto a descrição, tentei utilizar a flag, mas mesmo colocando o onclick, ele passa primeiro nesta validação, está fora do onclick. Utilizei o tempate de login do proprio android studio

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro A tela de registro será aberta somente se o botão for pressionado

Comment: Responda como resolveu e marque como fechada, ou escolha uma das respostas

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro não sei fechar, ou não aparece pra mim

Answer (score 2):

Fala Henrique,

Você pode usar a propriedade **Boolean**:

Você declara uma variável do tipo boolean, com o nome **clicked** e o valor padrão como **false**;

```
private boolean clicked = false;
```

Depois, dentro do click do botão, você altera essa variável pra **true**, dessa forma:

```
btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      clicked = true;

      if(clicked) {
          if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password))){
              mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
              mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
              focusView = mEmailView;
          }else{
              intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegistrarActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
      }
   }
});
```

Abraços.

Comment: Opa, talvez tenha ficado incompleto a descrição, tentei utilizar a flag, mas mesmo colocando o onclick, ele passa primeiro nesta validação, está fora do onclick. Utilizei o tempate de login do proprio android studio

Answer (score 0):

Talvez tenha entendido errado, porém, pelo que entendi ao clickar no btnRegistrar você irá verificar se os campos não estão vazios correto ?

Me parece que a validação estará dentro do evento OnClickListener então este trecho de código só será executado se o botão for pressionado, não há necessidade de verificar se foi clicado. Se você for checar se outro botão foi clicado, deve usar uma variável pra armazenar essa informação quando o outro evento for disparado.

Caso o motivo da sua verificação seja evitar que o botão seja nulo, esta verificação deve ser feita quando você atribui o valor à variável, pois ao não achar a view pode disparar uma NullPointerException.

E por último se você deseja armazenar uma configuração de modo mais permanente, considere trocar o button por um switch ou algo do tipo, pois o botao.isPressed() só retornará verdadeiro se o usuário ainda estiver apertando ele e não se foi pressionado.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição :)

Comment: Opa, talvez tenha ficado incompleto a descrição, tentei utilizar a flag, mas mesmo colocando o onclick, ele passa primeiro nesta validação, está fora do onclick. Utilizei o tempate de login do proprio android studio

Comment: Ah sim, bom, imagino que essa checagem esteja dentro de um onCreate() ou onStart() correto ? Se esse for o caso, essa checagem só será feita ao iniciar a Activity, o ideal é você chamar essa checagem depois que o botão for clicado, pois desta forma provavelmente o usuário já terá alterado os campos. Acredito que existam duas formas simples de solucionar isso, uma é colocar essa checagem dentro do evento, e você envolver o seu intent num `if(!cancel)` ou dentro do seu evento de click você chama um outro método contendo essa checagem e retornando o cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Eu declararia os EditText como global e no evento de click eu faria assim:

```
btnRegistrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_registrar_button);
btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(critica){
     intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegistrarActivity.class);
    //startNewIntent("registrar");
    }     
}});


private boolean critica() {
    if (mEmailView.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        return false;
    }

    if (mPasswordView.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```